# How do I return a promise resolve or reject from a function code inside router.post() in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

Below is my code in express(node.js)

```
router.post('/example.json', function (req, res) {

  // getFileInfo is a function to return a array
  return getFileInfo(req.body.fileList).then((array) => {

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost:5000/sendTestImage.json',
    data: {
      file: array
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }).catch((err) => {
    return Promise.reject();
  })
});
```

How do I return a Promise resolve or reject when finish axios call and return it to client which call "/example.json"?

Comment: First i want to know why do you need to resolve the promise here ?

Comment: because the client side use axis and will do something after promise resolve.

Comment: yeah I hope the client will do something after getting the response data. actually the call you are making itself an async call so when it's resolved it wll be coming to `.then` or if its getting rejected handler will be going to catch. You can send the data if your call is coming to `.then` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't return anything, if the call was success, just send the data to the client. If there was an error, set correct http response status and send error:

```
router.post('/example.json', function (req, res) {
  getFileInfo(req.body.fileList)
    .then(array => {
      return axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/sendTestImage.json',
        data: {
          file: array
        }
    })
    .then(data => res.send(data))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).send(err));
});
```

Comment: Really appreciated!